# PUG: How to make a button that links to another page, it is not working

Tags: html, button, hyperlink, pug

This is my code. I normally can do this in HTML but I am learning PUG. I don't know why the link is not working. I can't make it go to another HTML page.  I don't understand why it is not working.

thank you for your advise

[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjiJd.png)

Comment: Please read [ask], in particular the part about not posting pictures of text.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the highlighted line to a different type like this.

a(class='button' href='destinations.html' id="btn_destinations") Ir a destinos

it worked. I still don't understand why the previous one didn't work.